# How do I sync my folder to Amazon S3 in Java

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I am building a java application as a learning exercise. For now, I want to make an app that will take the contents in a folder and replicate it to my Amazon S3 bucket. By searching around, I found out that the best way to tell if 2 files are identical is to take the MD5 value.

How do I iteratively take the MD5 of each file in my bucket?

According to this link:
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/index.html?ListingObjectKeysUsingJava.html

The ObjectListing class can list the object keys and (metadata?) of your files in the bucket. But, it doesn't really specify how I can interact with the files. For example,
for my local files, I use guava and does something like this:

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
byte[] md4 = Files.getDigest(localFile, md);
```

Looking at the AWS S3 API, you can use S3Object.getObjectContent() which will return an InputStream. Is that the best way to work with the objects directly on S3?

Finally, what is the best way to sync from my local folder to a bucket in S3? Any tips is welcomed.

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ObjectListing objectListing = s3.listObjects(
  new ListObjectsRequest().withBucketName(bucket));
List<S3ObjectSummary> l = objectListing.getObjectSummaries();
```

`S3ObjectSummary` has memeber called `eTag` which is md5 hash of the object

Comment: Nice. Thanks!!! It's interesting that I can get the MD5 using eTag even if it is a folder but it gives me errors when I try to do Files.getDigest() on a folder. This works well though! Thanks again!

Comment: There is no concept of folder on amazon s3. simpli filenames that contain /. So, i dont really understand what do you mean by _"even it is a folder"_

Comment: Well, suppose you have a file in S3 called file1.txt and there will be a "folder" called /folder1. If there are no concepts of folders, that means that this file contains a others files which in my mind is a folder

Comment: @Yko, not really, your file1.txt is not actually called file1.txt but folder/file1.txt. The proof of that is that you can not list ***only *** the files in ***"current folder"***, but you can list files by prefix, and if your prefix is `folder/`, then you will get `folder/a.txt` and `folder/dir/b.txt`